# Splitting table using alphabet order in impala/ hive

Tags: join, hive, distance, impala

I have the following `FNAMES` table (it contains about 58k records)

```
+------+-------------+
| ID   |   NICKNAMES |
+------+-------------+
|  1   |  Avile      |
|  2   |  Dudi       |
|  3   |  Moshiko    |
|  4   |  Avi        |
|  5   |  DAVE       |
....
```

I would like to split the table by all the records that contain the same first lette, like this:

```
+------+-------------+
| ID   |   NICKNAMES |
+------+-------------+
|  1   |  Avile      |
|  4   |  Avi        |

|  2   |  Dudi       |
|  5   |  DAVE       |

|  3   |  Moshiko    |
....
```

For each split I would like to find the record with minimal `Jaro–Winkler distance`. It means for every letters that starts with 'a' I'll find the most similar record.
What do I have to change in the following code?

```
select FNAMES.*  ,  MIN(Jaro–Winkler(FNAMES.NICKNAMES, FNAMES.NICKNAMES))
from FNAMES
LEFT OUTER JOIN FNAMES
ON(true)
  WHERE Jaro–Winkler (FNAMES.NICKNAMES, FNAMES.NICKNAMES) <= 4
GROUP BY FNAMES.NICKNAMES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
select      f1.nicknames
           ,f2.nicknames

from       (select      f1.nicknames
                       ,f2.nicknames
                       ,rank () over
                        (
                            partition by    f1.nicknames
                            order by        jaro–winkler(f1.nicknames,f2.nicknames) desc
                        ) as rnk

            from                    fnames f1 

                        left join   fnames f2

                        on          substr(f1.nicknames,1,1) = 
                                    substr(f2.nicknames,1,1)

            where       f1.nicknames < f2.nicknames
            ) t

where       rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Dudu! Can you please add explanation to the code especially for the  f1.nicknames < f2.nicknames line. In addition, I changed the first select to select *, otherwise I get: "Semantic Exception 1007 Ambiguous column reference". And one additional point is jaro–winkler a built-in function in Hive/ Impala?

Comment: **(1)** Suppose you have a table with single column ''x' and 2 rows - 'A' and 'B'. `t1.x <> t2.x` will retun you both `A---B` and `B---A`. `t1.x < t2.x` will return only `A---B` (and not `B---A`). No point matching the same names in both directions. **(2)** I assume you got "Ambiguous column reference" because you added "create table ... as select ...". It is not an issue for a query ,e.g. - `select 1 as x,2 as x` is valid. **(3)** Not a built-in , but tou can download a UDF source code fom here: https://github.com/ychantit/fuzzymatch_hiveUDF.git